# how to set multiple data template to a listbox

Tags: wpf, templates, listbox, listbox-control

I have made 2 data templates and using it as a resource,i am applying it to a listbox,i am able to apply only a single data template on the listbox,here is the code for both data template

```
  <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="template1">
            <Canvas Height="40" Width="850">
                <Label Height="30" Width="170" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="80" Background="LightGray"></Label>
                <TextBox Height="30" Width="120" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="300" Background="AliceBlue"></TextBox>
                <Label Canvas.Left="420" Canvas.Top="5">$</Label>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="template2">
            <Canvas Height="40" Width="850">
                <Label Height="30" Width="200" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="80" Background="LightGray"></Label>
                <TextBox Height="30" Width="200" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="300" Background="AliceBlue"></TextBox>
                <Label Canvas.Left="420" Canvas.Top="5">$</Label>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
            </Window.Resources>
```

and the code for listbox

```
<TabItem>
        <Canvas Height="700" Width="850">
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Height="700" Width="850" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource template1}">
            </ListBox>
        </Canvas>
    </TabItem>
```

how can i apply both the data templates to the listbox,presently only "template1" is getting applied,how can "template2" be applied or if there are many data templates in future.,is there any way??,thanx

Comment: What actually you want? You can't have 2 DataTemplates for same object? Do you want template to be applied based on some condition?

Comment: i have listbox,in which i want multiple data templates to be displayed containing labels and textbox.

Comment: DataTemplate is a way to represent your data visually. Where are you setting ItemsSource of ListBox? DataTemplate can be switched based on some condition but you haven't mentioned any condition in your question. You can apply multiple DataTemplates using DataTemplateSelector though.

Comment: so without switching,just for displaying purpose we cannot apply?

Comment: If you want template for displaying purpose only then you need to change template for each listboxitem like this http://prntscr.com/3tb3bd

Comment: @HeenaPatil you may perhaps expand the comment with some relevant examples with some explanation on the same and provide as an answer so asker can also accept the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple DataTemplates using DataTemplateSelector and Datatrigger but you havent explain any condition(selected item,unselected item,index,change foreground and fontsize etc.)

It seems that you want template for displaying purpose/UI purpose only then you need to change template for each listboxitem like below

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="template1">
        <Canvas Height="40" Width="850">
            <Label Height="30" Width="170" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="80" Background="LightGray"></Label>
            <TextBox Height="30" Width="120" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="300" Background="AliceBlue"></TextBox>
            <Label Canvas.Left="420" Canvas.Top="5">$</Label>
        </Canvas>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="template2">        
        <Canvas Height="40" Width="850">
            <Label Height="30" Width="200" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="80" Background="LightGray"></Label>
            <TextBox Height="30" Width="200" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="300" Background="AliceBlue"></TextBox>
            <Label Canvas.Left="420" Canvas.Top="5">$</Label>
        </Canvas>     
    </ControlTemplate>      
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem>
            <Canvas Height="700" Width="850">
                <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Height="700" Width="850">
                    <ListBoxItem Template="{StaticResource template1}"></ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Template="{StaticResource template2}"></ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </Canvas>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: i have a xml file which contains many tasks,there are total 11 task, wanted to bind the the task to label for eg. task1 to template1 label,task2 to template2 label,task3 to template3 label... and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector Property [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Below I have a very simple example of a List of Student binded to ListBox and for the Student having Marks less than 50 percent I have Template2 and for others I selected Template1

View

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StudentDataTemplateSelector x:Key="studentDataTemplateSelector"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="template1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightGray">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RollNo}" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Percentage}" Margin="5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="template2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Red">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RollNo}" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Percentage}" Margin="5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Height="700" Width="850" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}"
             ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource studentDataTemplateSelector}">
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

xaml.cs

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
```

ViewModel / Student

```
    public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>{new Student{Name="ABC",RollNo=1,Percentage=86.5m},
            new Student{Name="DEF",RollNo=2,Percentage=76.5m},
            new Student{Name="GHI",RollNo=3,Percentage=66.5m},
            new Student{Name="JKL",RollNo=4,Percentage=56.5m},
            new Student{Name="MNO",RollNo=5,Percentage=46.5m},
            new Student{Name="PQR",RollNo=6,Percentage=36.5m},
        };
    }

}

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RollNo { get; set; }
    public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

ItemTemplateSelector

```
    public class StudentDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        var student = item as Student;
        if (student == null)
            return null;
        if (student.Percentage > 50)
            return
                element.FindResource("template1")
                as DataTemplate;
        else
            return
                element.FindResource("template2")
                as DataTemplate;
    }
}
```

I hope this will give you an idea.

Comment: thanx for your answer,i have got an idea now,but i dnt have any conditions i just want to bind my xml file content to each label  in the template,there are total 11 task, wanted to bind the the task to label for eg. task1 to template1 label,task2 to template2 label,task3 to template3 label... and so on.

Comment: Thank you for this. Really saved my hide as I wasn't quite sure how to approach my current predicament.